# Issues with value duplication in queryset filters

Tags: python, django

I am working on a web-application using django, and I would like to be able to return a queryset filter for a model that has no duplication. I know that distinct() exists but I do not know how to apply it on my code. I would like to return a list of cities from this queryset but not show duplicates.

I have already tried using if statements where the for loop is for the returned queryset with no success.

```
class StoreFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = {
            'city': ['icontains'],
        }

        def my_store_filter(self, queryset, city, value):
            return queryset.filter(**{
                city: value,
            })
```

Comment: You just add `.distinct()` at the end, so `return queryset.filter(..).distinct()`.

Comment: I am using sqlite

Comment: I just tried tacking it on at the end and it does not seem to work, same output

Comment: I think the problem is that cities have different IDs in the table but the same name. How can I filter by the name

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for here, why are you querying the store model for a list of cities?

Comment: A store has a city and name attached to it, I need the city names in a list so I can make that a page

Comment: You may need to share more information about your `Store` model and its (relevant) fields

Comment: I know a city table would make more sense but I feel as if its already too late to add that. It would take a lot of rewriting

Comment: class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'%s' % self.name

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55679776/edit) button

Comment: .distinct('id') ?

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi that wont work because there is a store with ID 1 whose city is x1, and a store with ID 2 whose city is also x1

Comment: They're suggesting to use `distinct('city')` however this isn't supported for sqlite